# PostgreSQL + Lazarus Pascal - failed connection during use

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, lazarus

I've built a program using Pascal + PG on a single PC running Ubuntu 12.04.

It's been working fine for about a month now, until this morning. So I'm not sure if it's an auto-update of the OS that did this.

While using the system, after about 30 minutes or so, I get a sudden error like this:

> connection to database failed (PostgreSQ:)

My only guess is that the DB session is closing (maybe I'm wrong). The only thing that solves the issue is to restart the application (i.e., my program) and things get to normal for another while.

My connection code is like this:

```
  dbConn:= TPQConnection.Create(nil);      
  dbConn.HostName := 'localhost';
  dbConn.DatabaseName:= 'MyDB';
  dbconn.UserName:='user';
  dbConn.Password:='pass';
  dbConn.Open;
    if dbConn.Connected Then
       OpenDB := true
    else
        OpenDB := False;
```

Has anyone come across something like this and is there a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Since your error message does not include any reason, you want to look at the server logs: `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log` in Ubuntu, replacing 9.1 by your version if necessary.